# Yu-Gi-Oh Tribute effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

When you activate a monsters tribute effect, like "tribute this monster to destroy a face up card on the field", can you tribute summon using that monster and activate its effect?

Answer (score 4):

No you would not get the effect if you used the stated monster as a tribute for something else.

The text states:

> "tribute this monster **to**"

this means tributing this card is a cost to activate the effect to destroy a face up card on the field.

if it read:

> **When/If** this monster is tributed

then it would work when you used it for a tribute summon or any effect that caused it to be tributed

Answer (score -2):

If you use "sphere mode" as a affect to tribute with other monsters on the fields and have the affect of dark "magician the dragon night" and "eternal soul"
"NOT CONFIRMED" your opponent can not tribute the card.